# Finding collocation matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, newton-series

$$ u_0, u_1, u_2 = 0, 1, 5$$

$$
p_0, p_1, p_2 = 1, 2, -6
$$

How can we derive a collocation matrix when the Newton's Polynomials are like this:

$$ P_i(u) = \prod^{i-1}_{j=0}(u-u_{i}) $$
$$ P_0(u) = 1 $$

The answer is supposed to be this:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 5 & 20 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

But I don't understand how. I understand it for the first column because $$P_0(u) = 1$$ but I don't get which exact values of $u$ are being used for for the other columns $P_1$ and $P_2$. I am probably interpreting the product expression wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column corresponds to a function $P_0, P_1$, and $P_2$ and the rows corresponds to the points $u_0, u_1, u_2$.

$$P_1(u)=u-u_0=u-0=u$$

Hence the second column just takes the value of $u_0, u_1, u_2$.

$$P_2(u)=(u-u_0)(u-u_1)$$

Hence the first two entries of it is $0$ and the last entry is

$$(u_2-u_1)(u_2-u_0)=5(4)=20$$

$p_i$ doesn't play a role in the current computation.

Comment: Is there formula for P(u) derived from the equation in the question? Or is it always like this? If it's a set formula, could you tell me what's it called so I can look it up online?

Comment: those polynomials are the [Newton basis polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial)